# Creating An Ordered List With Elements Not In (1,2,3,...) Order

Tags: enumerate

I am starting to do my math homework in LaTeX, but my math teacher assigns questions from the textbook not necessarily beginning with number 1, and he often skips questions. So, for example, he might assign question numbers beginning with (7,8,15,23,...), which my (very limited) understanding of LaTeX does not find possible. This is due to the fact that I can only find documentation on ordered lists beginning at one and proceeding in an orderly fashion. Is there a way to an ordered list with the proper formatting without typing something along the lines of the following?

```
\section{Questions}
7. 
8. 
15. 
23.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If you're using a `\begin{enumerate}` then you can do `\item[7]`, then `\item[8]`, then `\item[15]`...

Comment: Thank you so much!